# Object replacing previous data

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have function where i get an array and then i will return it as an object

The function is below

```
function arrayToObject(array) {
    var obj = {};

    for(var i = 0 ; i<array.length; i++){ 
        for(var j = 0; j<array[i].length; j++){
            console.log(array[i][j][0]
                                +"-"+
                        array[i][j][1]);
            obj[array[i][j][0]] = array[i][j][1];
        }
    }
    console.log("-----------");
    console.log(obj);
}
```

The array is

```
var array = [
[
    ['Vehicle', 'Car'], ['Engine', 'V6'], ['Year', 2001], ['Make', 'Holden']
]
,
[
    ['Vehicle', 'Car'], ['Engine', 'V8'], ['Year', 2001], ['Make', 'Holden']
]
];
```

I call it

```
arrayToObject(array);
```

And the out put is

```
Vehicle-Car    
Engine-V6    
Year-2001    
Make-Holden    
Vehicle-Car    
Engine-V8    
Year-2001
Make-Holden        
-----------    
{ Vehicle: 'Car', Engine: 'V8', Year: 2001, Make: 'Holden' }
```

It doesn't hold the previous car details

I have been trying to use Array.Reduce but i can't understand how to use it for nested arrays. If there is an easier way to do this that would be very helpful.

Comment: because its same property name hence gets override so it can't happen I guess you need and array of object here and not a single object

Comment: so whats the best way to do it? I was hoping to have one object for one vehicle

Comment: convert it to [{ Vehicle: 'Car', Engine: 'V8', Year: 2001, Make: 'Holden' },{ Vehicle: 'Car', Engine: 'V8', Year: 2001, Make: 'Holden' }] rather than single object does that make sense ?

Comment: Yes it does but how?

Comment: like this https://jsfiddle.net/yb5uLu1s/ is this what u need ?

Comment: [`return array.map(arr => arr.reduce((a, b) => {
    a[[b[0]]] = b[1];
    return a;
}, {}));`](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/0gyh6fr4/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same property name shall be override in an object hence convert it to array of objects like this

```
[{ Vehicle: 'Car', Engine: 'V8', Year: 2001, Make: 'Holden' },{ Vehicle: 'Car', Engine: 'V8', Year: 2001, Make: 'Holden' }]
```

as follows

```js
var array = [
[
    ['Vehicle', 'Car'], ['Engine', 'V6'], ['Year', 2001], ['Make', 'Holden']
]
,
[
    ['Vehicle', 'Car'], ['Engine', 'V8'], ['Year', 2001], ['Make', 'Holden']
]
];

var arrR = [];
array.forEach(function(ele){
var temp = {};
  ele.forEach(function(innerEle){
   temp[innerEle[0]] = innerEle[1]
  });
  arrR.push(temp);
})

console.log(arrR)
```

Comment: wow thanks man, i just need to get my head around this function of yours

Comment: I just found that if i declare an empty array like how you have done and then add my object in the parent array then that solves the problem too cheers

Answer (score 0):

here's the solution using `map` and `reduce`:

```js
let result = array.map(function(properties) {
 return properties.reduce(function(acc, property) {
   acc[property[0]] = property[1];
   return acc;
 }, {});
});
```

Answer (score -1):

I made for es6 here with reduce and map

https://es6console.com/iywjoob3/

```
function arrayToObject(array) {
    const obj = array.map(car =>  {
      return car.map(k => ({ [k[0]]: k[1] })).reduce((p, c) => Object.assign(p, c), {})
    })
    console.log("-----------");
    console.log(obj);
}
```